# How do I lookbehind for a single word?

Tags: regex, lookbehind

In this string `a b-cd`, I want to apply this regex `a b-c(?<=a)d`.

The only way is to write it like that `a b-c(?<=a b-c)d`, but I do not want to write the entire regex behind it to apply it and only want to see if this letter exists or not.

a complex version of it: `(?:[a-z] )?b c d e f(?:(?<=a ) alphas)`
https://regex101.com/r/gyT6ix/1

Is this possible?

[Regex Lookaround Reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: You can do something like this https://regex101.com/r/zrzYld/1/

Comment: You want to determine if there is an `a` before the `d`? Which tool or programming language do you use?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes PCRE.

Comment: @CodeManiac the string could be longer than this like `a b-cdaxyza` i use for it `a b-c(?:(?<=a)d)` so i can not use lookahead for that because i want to determine from the start of the string if it has an `a`

Comment: @JoeDoe Is this about a word or a letter? This pattern `a b-c(?<=a)d` does not match because you match c and then assert what is on the left is a. The second pattern matches `a b-c(?<=a b-c)d` because you immediately assert what is on the left what you have just matched.

Comment: @Thefourthbird all about the letter i only want to tell if there is an letter `a` at the back of the string of the written point of `d` so if there is an `a` the `d` is allowed

Comment: Do you mean like this: `^[^a]*a[^d]*d` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/924aWw/1) or `^[^a]*\ba\b[^d]*d` with a word boundary `\b` for a

Comment: @Thefourthbird a more complex example of why i want to use lookbehind is something like this pattern `(?:[a-z] )?b c d e f(?:(?<=a ) alphas)` for this string `a b c d e f alphas` only to check the variable `[a-z]` if it is an `a` to allow writing `alphas` as here https://regex101.com/r/gyT6ix/1 but the one works is like this by writing everything at the back https://regex101.com/r/gyT6ix/2

Comment: @Thefourthbird i thought about using `a b-c(?<=a.*)d` but did not work either can't it be used to lookbehind for a single letter instead of looking for everything that exists in the string?

Comment: But this would match it right? `[^a\n]*a.*?\balphas\b` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9fm1q/1) This pattern `a b-c(?<=a.*)d` does not work in pcre due to the quantifier `*` in the lookbehind that is not supported. It does for example in .NET regex.

Comment: @Thefourthbird but now it will not follow the strict formula of the strings which depends on `b c d e f` as a main part of it and the `[a-z]` to be anything but if it is `a` then `alphas` must be written

Comment: @JoeDoe You might use an if else construction `(?(?=a)a b c d e f alphas\b|[a-z] b c d e f)`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ly3XSo/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pcre the infinite lookbehind `.*` in patttern `a b-c(?<=a.*)d` as you refer to in the comments is not supported.

One option to match either `[a-z] b c d e f` or `a b c d e d alphas` could be to use an [if-then-else conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) looking like `(?(?=regex)then|else)`

```
(?(?=a)\ba b c d e f alphas\b|[a-z] b c d e f)
```

**About the regex**

- `(?` If clause

  - `(?=a)` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is `a`
  - `\ba b c d e f alphas\b` Match `a b c d e f alphas` and use word boundaries to prevent a and alphas being part of a larger word
- `|` Or
- `[a-z] b c d e f` Match char a-z followed by  b c d e f
  )

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PmVKaz/1)